# Are there "high level" versions of all bosses?

Tags: darkest-dungeon

One mission type one encounters in Darkest Dungeon" are missions where you have to kill a specific boss. One of them is the swine prince.
If I would spare him for now, will the game create high level-version of the boss? Or will this boss fight be always a low level mission?

To ask it more general: Do bosses have a fixed level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: the Apprentice version of the Swine Prince will always be available to kill as an Apprentice level mission (suitable for adventurers of resolve level 0-2).  As long as there are Apprentice adventurers available (a suggested early upgrade is getting the Stagecoach to provide at least 4 newbies every week), you will be able to do that adventure whenever you please.

Longer answer: there are versions of each boss at each of the three tiers: Apprentice, Veteran, Champion.  They will appear eventually (generally requiring you to clear out the previous version of the boss/explore enough) and be there until you clear them, and there's no time limit in the base game so you can get to it whenever it suits you.  The bosses get more difficult at higher tiers.  Their stats increase and their abilities hit harder/have nastier status effects/have a more likely chance to cause those status effects.  All of this applies for both the main bosses in each area, and the optional bosses that appear once you kill the main boss at a given level.

You mentioned the Swine Prince, his later "forms" are the Swine King (Veteran) and the Swine God (Champion).

Answer (score 2):

After you beat the low-level boss mission, you will eventually open up a medium-level boss fight mission.  After you beat that you will eventually open a high-level boss mission.  The bosses have similar names across difficulty levels.  You can see this by scrolling through the list of the Keeper's missions/achievements.

Once you can build a party that is sufficiently strong enough to fight a boss, you should attempt the dungeon.  Recall that, for example, level 3+ heroes cannot participate in a level 1 mission.  This means that if you wait too long to fight a boss, your party members may become too strong and you will have to train up new ones.

One tip: For the low- and mid-level boss fights (I haven't reached the high-level fights yet), the Hag is MUCH more difficult than the Swine or Necromancer of the same level.